# React/Jest - Render connected HOC component in Jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I've been playing around with unit tests in React and HOC. I have a higher order component that returns a new WrapperComponent. Additionally, when returning the WrapperComponent, I am also connecting it with props and other HOC's, like mapStateToProps, etc. What I'm struggling with is how to properly render the HOC that's been composed with other HOC's. I'm sure I'm missing some concept.

Inspecting `hoc` reveals that it is a function, which makes sense with HOC's, but when I try to shallow render `hoc`, I get the following error: `encountered declaration error`.

HOC - some code removed for brevity

```
export default function withComposition(WrappedComponent) {
    class CompositionComponent extends Component {

        static displayName = `withComposition(${WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name})`;

        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent
                    {...this.props}
                />
            );
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        isMounted: selectIsMounted(state),
    });

    const enhance = compose(
        connect(mapStateToProps),
        withTranslate,
    );

    return enhance(CompositionComponent);
}
```

Unit Test

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withComposition from '../modules/withComposition';

describe('CompositionComponent', () => {   
    const hoc = withComposition(<Component />);
    debugger;
    const wrapper = shallow(hoc);
});
```

I am also getting the following error, which I think is strange as my other tests uses the `shallow` method and does not raise any issue.

`Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOC returns component, so to the `shallow` you should pass JSX component:

```
describe('CompositionComponent', () => {   
    const Hoc = withComposition(<Component />);
    debugger;
    const wrapper = shallow(<Hoc foo="foo" bar="bar" />);
});
```